# React JS - How to get multiple location info as autocomplete in a single input

Tags: html, reactjs, autocomplete

I have a single input:

```
<input autoComplete='street-address' value={location} />
```

I'd like to get not only the user's street address as a hint but also a locality, postal code, etc... in the same input, that's possible?

I Searched through the documentation but I only found examples with multiple inputs but that's not what I'm searching for.

Edit:
I'll try to elaborate my question hiding sensitive data:
When I tap on my input I get, as hint, my home full address but when I tap on it the input is filled only with my street address.

Take a look at the screenshots below

[image]

[image]

Comment: please elaborate the question, with code and screenshots if possible

Comment: @ShubhdeepChhabra Thanks for the answer, tell me if now the question is more clear